# Interesting examples of differentiation under the integral sign?

Tags: calculus, integration, big-list, leibniz-integral-rule

I was recently looking through integration techniques when I came upon differentiation under the integral sign (DUIS).  It seems to be pretty powerful, for example:

$$f(t)=\int_0^1\frac{x^t-1}{\ln(x)}\ dx\implies f'(t)=\int_0^1x^t\ dx=\frac1{t+1}\\\implies f(t)=C+\ln(t+1)\\f(0)=0\implies C=0\\\implies\int_0^1\frac{x^t-1}{\ln(x)}\ dx=\ln(t+1)$$

Now, on my own, proving that $\int_0^1\frac{x^t-1}{\ln(x)}\ dx=\ln(t+1)$ would've been a hefty task without DUIS, and so I wanted to ask this question:

> It's hard to produce interesting examples where applying DUIS is almost magical, so what are some good example uses of DUIS?

Comment: Feynman was a big fan of differentiating under the integral.  These notes from Keith Conrad look interesting: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf   Also these notes might be interesting: https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Feynman.pdf  See also: "Integration: The Feynman Way": http://fy.chalmers.se/~tfkhj/FeynmanIntegration.pdf

Comment: @littleO Ah thanks!  It even has my example on page nine.  :D

Comment: Wikipedia has a good list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Examples_for_evaluating_a_definite_integral), 8 examples including your own

Comment: This is really the sort of thing that you can just Google.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 well yeah, but some friends and I wanted a list of interesting integrals here on MSE.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a rare example involving high-order DUIS

$$I_n(t)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{t\cos\theta}\cos(n\theta+t\sin\theta)d\theta
$$
Differentiate to establish
$$I_n’(t)= I_{n+1}(t)$$
along with $I_1(t)=0$.
which results in
\begin{align}
I_{n}(t) = \frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}I_1(t)=0
\end{align}