# Evaluating $\int_0^1 \frac{x^3-1}{\ln x}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

> The question is to evaluate $$\int_0^1 \frac{x^3-1}{\ln x}dx$$

I tried to put $t=\ln x$ so $dt=\frac1xdx$.Hence I could rewrite the integral as $$\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{e^{3x}-1}{x}e^xdx$$I couldnot further simplify the integral.Any ideas?Thanks.

Comment: What does Wolfram say?

Comment: This (or a more general integral) has been asked for before. You can have a look at the (only some hours old) question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2157226/97236) for one way to calculate it. But I know it has been asked and answered before (I just cannot find the right link).

Comment: @mickep lol, you can't really expect that.  I wouldn't have seen that if looking for duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2157226/interesting-examples-of-differentiation-under-the-integral-sign), it's easy enough to take a more general problem:

$$f(t)=\int_0^1\frac{x^t-1}{\ln(x)}\ dx$$

Differentiate with respect to $t$ and you'll get

$$f'(t)=\int_0^1x^t\ dx=\frac1{t+1}$$

Integrate both sides from zero to one to reveal

$$f(t)=\ln(t+1)$$

> $$\int_0^1\frac{x^t-1}{\ln(x)}\ dx=\ln(t+1)$$

With $t=3$ being your integral.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 7):

Note that substituting $x=e^{-t}$, your integral becomes $$\int_0^1 \frac{x^3-1}{\ln x}\mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}-e^{-4t}}{t} \mathrm{d} t$$

As $\ln x =-t$.  Now use [Frullani's Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html) to get that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}-e^{-4t}}{t} \mathrm{d} t=\ln \frac{-4}{-1}=\ln 4$$

As corroborated [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+from+0+to+1+(x%5E3-1)%2Fln+x). We are done!

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt The someone has undownvoted since then.

Answer (score 1):

$$\displaystyle  \int^{1}_{0}\frac{x^3-1}{\ln x}dx = \int^{1}_{0}\left(\int^{3}_{0}x^{ t}dt\right)dx =  \int^{3}_{0}\left(\int^{1}_{0}x^{t}dx\right)dt$$

So $$\displaystyle \int^{3}_{0}\left(\frac{x^{t+1}}{t+1}\right)\bigg|_{0}^{1}dt = \int^{3}_{0}\frac{1}{t}dt = \ln(t+1)\bigg|_{0}^{3} = \ln (4)$$