# Is there any other method of integration? besides the best known .

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Is there any other method of integration besides the best known as:

- Substitution,
- Integration by parts,
- Trigonometric,
- Trigonometric Substitutions,
- Partial Fractions,
- Improper Integrals, and
- Laplace?

Some method that is taught in doctorates etc...

Comment: The question is a bit broad.

Comment: You could read about "differentiating under the integral sign". See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2157226/interesting-examples-of-differentiation-under-the-integral-sign.

Comment: If $$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k c_k x^{2k}$$ then $$\int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx = \frac{\pi}{2}c_{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: @CountIblis is that a special case of Ramanujan's master theorem?

Comment: @clathratus Yes!

Answer (score 5):

Integration by differentiating under the integral, integration by residue theorem, integration by complexification etc. There are of course a large number of fields of which integration covers.